# Is it possible to check Hidden field or text field in post of a form?

Tags: php, html, forms, post

**Is it possible?**

My question is that :

I have a form having fields like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="chargetotal_reload_uk" name="chargetotal" value="12.01" />
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="xyz" />
```

and another form:

```
<input type="hidden" id="chargetotal_reload_uk" name="chargetotal" value="12.01" />
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="xyz" />
```

In both cases:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

give me:

```
array(
 'chargetotal'=>'12.01',
 'name'=>'xyz',
);
```

**Is it possible to identify hidden field in `$_POST` ie `chargetotal` was  the hidden field in the form?**

Comment: No, the type of the field is not accessible to PHP through the `$_POST` variable. Assuming you're following standards and using unique names for each field, however, you should already know which fields are `type='hidden'`.

Comment: Why do you want identify hidden field ? You have his name.

Comment: No, php is unaware of the type of html field

Comment: If you can explain *why* you need this information, perhaps we can suggest some alternatives.

Comment: You could keep this info somewhere serverside in an array i.e.

Comment: I'd assume you could do something like `if($_POST['chargetotal']) == "12.01"; {...}` or `if(isset($_POST['chargetotal'])){...}` or `if(!empty($_POST['chargetotal'])){...}`- As Lix said, give us an explanation as to why you want to do this. Yet, I suggest you give both your form elements in each forms, different names in order to know which one was set/empty etc. I.e.: `name="chargetotal_1"` and `name="chargetotal_2"`, that would work.

Comment: @HorsSujet only to check Is it possible.

Comment: @Lix Thanks for response. I just want to check is it possible or not.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Actually I want to check the possibility of it.

Comment: It is; to a certain extent. Theoretically and as per my comment above.

Comment: @Fred-ii- No, Actually problem was that.I have a payment form.I set this field value with jquery But when the field type is hidden ,it don't form. but when type is text, it works. This form action is  the payment gateway url which give invalid amount error . Due to this problem I asked this question.

Comment: @Lix  Actually problem was that.I have a payment form.I set this field value with jquery But when the field type is hidden ,it don't form. but when type is text, it works. This form action is the payment gateway url which give invalid amount error . Due to this problem I asked this question.

Comment: You can use sessions then, set a variable for it in your hidden field, then run it through both PHP and jQuery.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes I did it like this.But the question is that why is it happening?

Comment: I'll post an answer to show you what works for me.

Comment: I've posted an answer below, along with what the HTML/source output was.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, you should probably already know the names of your hidden fields, but technically, you could pass the field type in with the name, then explode on the $_POST keys in your script.

**HTML**

```
<input type="hidden" id="chargetotal_reload_uk" name="charge total::hidden" value="12.01" />
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="xyz" />
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$vars = array();
foreach($_POST as $key => $val){
    if(sibstr_count($key, '::') > 0){
        $key = explode('::'. $key);
        $vars[$key[0]] = array('fieldType' => $key[1]. 'value' => $val);
    } else {
        $vars[$key] = $val;
        // or $vars[$key] = array('fieldType' => ''. 'value' => $val); if you need to keep the same format
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response . but I want to check the possibility of it weather it is possible or not. Now I got that it is not possible.

Comment: Actually problem was that.I have a payment form.I set this field value with jquery But when the field type is hidden ,it don't form. but when type is text, it works. This form action is the payment gateway url which give invalid amount error . Due to this problem I asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment on usage, you can use PHP [**sessions**](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) for this.

You would need to set your value in `$_SESSION['value'] = "12.01";` for it to work.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['value'] = "12.01";
?>

<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['value']) || !empty($_SESSION['value'])) { 

echo "The value is: " . $_SESSION['value'];

}
    else {
        echo "<div id='session_name'>No value set.</div>";
      }
?>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
var thevalue = "<?php echo $_SESSION['value']; ?>";

// alert (thevalue);

    });
</script>

<br><br>

<input type="hidden" id="chargetotal_reload_uk" name="chargetotal" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['value']; ?>" />

<div id="session_name">The value is: <?php echo $_SESSION['value']; ?></div>
```

---

HTML source/output:

```
The value is: 12.01
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
var thevalue = "12.01";

// alert (thevalue);

    });
</script>

<br><br>

<input type="hidden" id="chargetotal_reload_uk" name="chargetotal" value="12.01" />

<div id="session_name">The value is: 12.01</div>
```